# Create table in Latex, then save it as image in vector graphics format

Tags: graphics

I have created a table in Latex, and I would now like to save the table as an image using a vector graphics format such as EPS. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Compile only your table with no page number and run `latex+dvips` to obtain a ps file. Or run `pdflatex` to obtain a pdf file. Configure the margin to reduce white space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use the [standalone](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class for this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcr} \toprule
Left & Center & Right \\ \midrule
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

At least on OS X, building to a PDF and using `pdf2ps` results in a PostScript file that has a BoundingBox directive, which should be enough to include in other documents. Or you can build with regular LaTeX to make a DVI, and convert the DVI to a PS as Sigur recommended.