# Export each table and figure as an image in vector graphics format through overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, overleaf, export

I have tables and figures in LaTeX through [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/). I would like to save the tables and tikz figures as separate images using a vector graphics format such as EPS. Is there a way I can do this on [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/)?

**The main reason** is I am going to submit a paper to a journal that has only .doc template. So it does not accept files on LaTeX even I offered to format the paper based on their structuring rules. However, I have already written my side on LaTeX, which means I have to move to their template side. In this case, I assume that the best way is to export tikz figures and tables as vector images (.eps) and then copy/paste the rest of the paper (mainly text parts) in order to complete the transfer fully. What do you think about this idea as well ?

Comment: You can compile your figures with the [standalone](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=de) class. This will produce PDF files containing just the content. PDF is also a vector format, but if you need another format you can convert the PDF with various softwares.

Comment: What marv said, plus a similar solution for [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/206699/21344)